# Value cannot be null when deserializing JSON

Tags: c#, winforms, json.net

I have a db table which has column in which content is stored in JSON format, I am retrieving JSON but I am getting this error.
**Value cannot be null**
Here is my code snippet.

```
var stuff = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(commentId);

string name = stuff["Name"].Value<string>();
string email = stuff["Email"].Value<string>();
string company = stuff["Company"].Value<string>();
string phone = stuff["Phone"].Value<string>();
string message = stuff["Message"].Value<string>();
string emails = stuff["Emails"].Value<string>();
```

My sample JSON:

```
{
  "2": {
    "label": "",
    "value": "",
    "type": null,
    "validation": null,
    "required": null,
    "min": null,
    "max": null,
    "tooltip": null,
    "custom": null,
    "custom2": null,
    "custom3": "zz",
    "custom4": null,
    "custom5": null
  },
  "3": {
    "label": "location",
    "value": "http://someurl.com/",
    "type": "hidden",
    "validation": "",
    "required": "0",
    "min": "0",
    "max": "1000",
    "tooltip": "",
    "custom": null,
    "custom2": null,
    "custom3": "zz",
    "custom4": null,
    "custom5": null
  },
  "4": {
    "label": "Name*",
    "value": "Farrukh",
    "type": "text",
    "validation": "alphabets",
    "required": "1",
    "min": "0",
    "max": "300",
    "tooltip": "field0",
    "custom": "",
    "custom2": null,
    "custom3": "zz",
    "custom4": null,
    "custom5": null
  },
  "5": {
    "label": "Email*",
    "value": "abc@a.com",
    "type": "email",
    "validation": "email",
    "required": "1",
    "min": "",
    "max": "",
    "tooltip": "field1",
    "custom": "autoreply",
    "custom2": "replyto",
    "custom3": "zz",
    "custom4": "",
    "custom5": ""
  },
  "6": {
    "label": "Company",
    "value": "Abc",
    "type": "text",
    "validation": "",
    "required": "1",
    "min": "0",
    "max": "300",
    "tooltip": "field2",
    "custom": "",
    "custom2": null,
    "custom3": "zz",
    "custom4": null,
    "custom5": null
  },
  "7": {
    "label": "Phone",
    "value": "0000000000",
    "type": "text",
    "validation": "integers",
    "required": "0",
    "min": "0",
    "max": "300",
    "tooltip": "field3",
    "custom": "",
    "custom2": null,
    "custom3": "zz",
    "custom4": null,
    "custom5": null
  },
  "8": {
    "label": "Country",
    "value": "Some country",
    "type": "dropdown",
    "validation": "",
    "required": "1",
    "min": "",
    "max": "",
    "tooltip": "field4",
    "custom": null,
    "custom2": null,
    "custom3": "zz",
    "custom4": null,
    "custom5": null
  },
  "9": {
    "label": "Message*",
    "value": "hello",
    "type": "para",
    "validation": "",
    "required": "1",
    "min": "0",
    "max": "3000",
    "tooltip": "field5",
    "custom": "",
    "custom2": null,
    "custom3": "zz",
    "custom4": null,
    "custom5": null
  },
  "10": {
    "label": "name",
    "value": "",
    "type": null,
    "validation": null,
    "required": null,
    "min": null,
    "max": null,
    "tooltip": null,
    "custom": null,
    "custom2": null,
    "custom3": "zz",
    "custom4": null,
    "custom5": null
  },
  "11": {
    "label": "title",
    "value": "",
    "type": null,
    "validation": null,
    "required": null,
    "min": null,
    "max": null,
    "tooltip": null,
    "custom": null,
    "custom2": null,
    "custom3": "zz",
    "custom4": null,
    "custom5": null
  },
  "12": {
    "label": "emails",
    "value": ",a@a.com,b@b.com,c@c.com,d@d.com",
    "type": null,
    "validation": null,
    "required": null,
    "min": null,
    "max": null,
    "tooltip": null,
    "custom": null,
    "custom2": null,
    "custom3": "zz",
    "custom4": null,
    "custom5": null
  },
  "13": {
    "label": "multi",
    "value": "true",
    "type": null,
    "validation": null,
    "required": null,
    "min": null,
    "max": null,
    "tooltip": null,
    "custom": null,
    "custom2": null,
    "custom3": "zz",
    "custom4": null,
    "custom5": null
  },
  "0": {
    "custom3": "zz",
    "value": "",
    "label": ""
  },
  "1": {
    "custom3": "zz",
    "value": "",
    "label": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: could you please provide content of "commentId"? And possibly it does not contain either Name, Email, Company, or...

Comment: One of the values does't exist in your `JObject`. Did you try debugging your code?

Comment: post your JObject code

Comment: Here is my JObject code.

"4": { "label": "Name*", "value": "Farrukh", "type": "text", "validation": "alphabets", "required": "1", "min": "0", "max": "300", "tooltip": "field0", "custom": "", "custom2": null, "custom3": "zz", "custom4": null, "custom5": null }, "5": { "label": "Email*", "value": "Farrukh@xyx.com", "type": "email", "validation": "email", "required": "1", "min": "", "max": "", "tooltip": "field1", "custom": "autoreply", "custom2": "replyto", "custom3": "zz", "custom4": "", "custom5": "" }

Comment: Please edit your question and post the JSON in a formatted format.

Comment: "4": {
    "label": "Name*",
    "value": "Farrukh",
    "type": "text",
    "validation": "alphabets",
    "required": "1",
    "min": "0",
    "max": "300",
    "tooltip": "field0",
    "custom": "",
    "custom2": null,
    "custom3": "zz",
    "custom4": null,
    "custom5": null
  },

Comment: The JSON you posted does not correlate to your code. In your code you are expecting objects of `Name`, `Email`, etc. But in your JSON you have *values* that represent that. You will need to adjust your code to fit to your JSON

Comment: Can you give me a code snippet?

Comment: Before I post a code snippet, please confirm if the entire JSON is not inside an array (aka starts at the top with `{ xxx: [` and ends with `] }`

Comment: var stuff = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(commentId);
I think you want to deserialize comment object not the id property of comment object id.

Comment: No it start like this.

Comment: I want to deserialize the commentID as I am retrieving JSON in that variable.

Comment: @FarrukhAhmed if your JSON is very big, *sanitize* it first (Remove emails, personal info, etc.), then paste it [here](http://pastebin.com/) and give us the link. That way we can see the complete raw format of the JSON you have in commentID.

Comment: @Bernd Linde it is not an array.

Comment: @BerndLinde I edit my post.
You can now see my complete JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your full JSON is as you show, your JSON doesn't give simple name/value pairs for name and email.  Instead it has a dictionary of indexed property objects, where each object has a `label` property with value equal to the name of property you seek, and an adjacent `value` property with the corresponding value.

You can conveniently fetch these from your JSON by building an ancillary [lookup table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549211%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) as follows:

```
        var dict = JObject.Parse(commentId)
            .Descendants()
            .OfType<JProperty>()
            .Where(p => p.Name == "label")
            .ToLookup(p => (string)p.Value, p => (string)p.Parent["value"]); // Use ToLookup because some empty space keys are duplicated
        var name = dict["Name*"].SingleOrDefault(); // Notice the asterisk in the property labels.
        var email = dict["Email*"].SingleOrDefault();
```

And, to test:

```
        Debug.Assert(name == "Farrukh"); // No assert.
        Debug.Assert(email == "abc@a.com"); // No assert.
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that when you do

```
string name = stuff["Name"].Value<string>();
```

and the others you are getting the value for stuff["Name"] and if it doesn't have that property in the JSON, for this example it doesn't have "Name" it will throw you "Value cannot be null"

So you need first to check if you have the values or not.

You can check like that

```
//check if property exists
if (stuff["Name"].Value<string>()!= null) {
    string name = stuff["Name"].Value<string>();
} else {
    //there is no "name" property, compensate somehow.
}
```

Comment: Or just use an [explicit cast](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_op_Explicit_28.htm) and do `var name = (string)stuff["Name"];` -- that's null-safe.

Comment: But I am getting JSON it have all the properties.

Comment: If you post your JSON maybe I can help more. It may be problem with the deserializing.

Comment: "4": {
    "label": "Name*",
    "value": "Farrukh",
    "type": "text",
    "validation": "alphabets",
    "required": "1",
    "min": "0",
    "max": "300",
    "tooltip": "field0",
    "custom": "",
    "custom2": null,
    "custom3": "zz",
    "custom4": null,
    "custom5": null
  },
  "5": {
    "label": "Email*",
    "value": "Farrukh@xyx.com",
    "type": "email",
    "validation": "email",
    "required": "1",
    "min": "",
    "max": "",
    "tooltip": "field1",
    "custom": "autoreply",
    "custom2": "replyto",
    "custom3": "zz",
    "custom4": "",
    "custom5": ""
  }

Comment: It is something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty old topic, but I am using:

`string name = stuff["Name"]?.Value<string>() ?? "undefined";
string email = stuff["Email"]?.Value<string>() ?? "undefined";`

Concise and simple and also provides your own default value.